# fetch emails from mysql db using pdo using multiple ids in textbox

Tags: php, mysql, email, pdo, textbox

I have a form that contains a textbox that the user can ad `member ids` to. each id is separated by a space in the textbox. When the user submits the form I want to fetch each members' `email` from mysql db and include a string for each email within the php script that sends the e-mail.

**Textbox Values**

```
101 107 212
```

**DB Colomns**

```
ID - EMAIL - NAME<br>
101 - example@xyz.com - Example
107 - johndoe@abc.com - John Doe
212 - frank@bbjfk.com - Frank Ford
```

**Output in Php Script**

```
mail( 'Example &lt;example@xyz.com&gt;' , $subject , $message , $headers);
mail( 'John Doe &lt;johndoe@abc.com&gt;' , $subject , $message , $headers);
mail( 'Frank Ford &lt;frank@bbjfk.com&gt;' , $subject , $message , $headers);
```

I have looked for an example on how to write this into my mail() php script but have not found anything. My first task is to fetch the related records then to write them as individual strings that the php script uses. FYI - the number of ids in the `textbox` can range from one to six ids.

Any starter tips/examples would be greatly appreciated.

**Addressing My First Task**

To fetch the appropriate records from mysql db named "members", I have come up with the following. The name of my textbox is "MemberIDs".

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $MemberIDs = $_POST['MemberIDs'];
    $SearchIDs = array($MemberIDs);
    $SearchStr = implode(' ', $SearchIDs); // returns 101 107 212
    $pdos = "SELECT * FROM members where id in ({$SearchStr})";
    $pdos->execute();
    $results = $pdos->fetchAll();
}
```

Before I setup the test to see if this works, does this look correct for finding the records I want to get e-mails from?

Comment: Show Us Your Code, Which You Tried From Your End. First Know How To Execute Multiple Textbox. Put It In For Loop. Inside For Loop. Execute Your Query To Find Mail.

Comment: @nana I updated my question

Comment: Please show your html <form> code too @Cliff.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL `IN` statement must use commas instead of spaces as delimiters.

```
// Assuming this POST variable contains a string
// looking like "101 107 212".
$SearchIDs = explode(' ', $_POST['MemberIDs']);

// You HAVE to sanitize the user input. ALWAYS.
array_walk($searchIDs, function(&item, $key){
    // Make sure every item is a number and not some gibberish.
    $item = (int) trim($item);
    if ($item <= 0) {
        unset($item);
    }
});

// Make a comma-separated string to use in the IN statement.
$inIDs = implode(",", $searchIDs);

// Build the query, at last.
$pdos = "SELECT * FROM members where id in ({$inIDs})";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will setup a test based on your advise and get back with results.

Comment: Thanks for your input Sergey I appreciate your time. I ended up using a solution using mysqli vs pdo.

Comment: Not sure what difference it would make in this particular case, but good to know that the problem's solved.